# What distribution can random sampling of sequencing reads from a genome be described by?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution

I work with Nanopore DNA sequencing and do a taxonomic classification of each read - that is to infer which species it originated from. However, this process is not perfect because of the available databases, and so I want to filter the results afterwards.

For the true positive identifications I expect the DNA reads to be spread fairly even across the genome from which it originated like this (where each number represents the count of reads in a given window of the genome):

```
2 3 4 3 2 4 2 4 3 4 2 1 3 5 3 2 1 3 6
```

And for the false positive identifications the distribution could look like this, with an uneven spread:

```
0 1 8 0 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 2 3 1
```

My initial thought was to test if the counts follow a Poisson distribution. In its ideal reads are sampled completely random across the genome, but it seems that even for some known true positives the distribution is not a Poisson.

Another challenge is that each genome will have a different number of windows.

So first, I would like to ask, if indeed such a scenario (if completely ideal) indeed follows a Poisson distribution?

And secondly, can I make any modifications to my approach that might help facilitate such a test?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate further on "but it seems that even for some known true positives the distribution is not a Poisson" ?

Comment: Yes! The way I went about it was to take the window with the highest number of reads (counts) to evaluate the probability of that count coming from a poisson distribution with a given lambda.